# VideoJS How to obtain current time

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have problems to retrieve information about currentMilis in video.js. I have the next code:

**Player.js**

```
(function(){

  PlayerGam = function( container ){

    this._video = new videojs( container );

    _init.apply( this );
  };

  var _init = function(){
    this._video.on( 'ended', _onEnded );
    this._video.on( 'loadeddata', _onLoadedData );
    this._video.on( 'timeupdate', _onTimeUpdate );
    this._video.on( 'useractive', _onUserActive );
    this._video.on( 'userinactive', _onUserInactive );
    this._video.on( 'volumechange', _onVolumeChange );
  };

  var _onEnded = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: Ended video ' + evt );
  };

  var _onLoadedData = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: Loaded Data ' + evt );
  };

  var _onTimeUpdate = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: Time update ' + this._video.currentTime() );
  };

  var _onUserActive = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] videoJS: User active ' + evt );
  };

  var _onUserInactive = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: User inactive ' + evt );
  };

  var _onVolumeChange = function(evt){
    console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: Volume Change ' + evt );
  };

})();
```

**instance.js**

```
(function(){

  var instance = new PlayerGam( 'example_video' );

})();
```

**Html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> VideoJS - Test 3 </title>

    <link href="./styles/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <video id="example_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640" height="380">
        <source src="http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/vast_inspector/android.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></source>
      </video>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/video.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="./js/player_gam.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="./js/instance.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have the next error on my browser console:

```
TypeError: this._video is undefined


console.log( '[Video][Gam] VideoJS: Time update ' + this._video.currentTime() )
```

Any help could be usefull,

Thanks, Jaster.

Answer (score 0):

Within the event callback, `this` will be the player. You should use `this.currentTime()`.